# Should auto-renamed files get consecutive numbers?

Tags: files, content-management

If we select a bunch of files and bulk-rename them all to "Name", they will usually get names like "Name(1)", "Name(2)", "Name(3)" etc.

If then we go on to delete "Name(2)", and then take a new file and try renaming it to "Name" - should it get "Name(4)", or should it use the "gap" we've created and get "Name(2)"?

I tend towards the "highest+1" approach, but Windows seems to be taking the "filling gaps" approach.

Comment: Does it matter from user perspective? It's an arbitrary name either way, something that always will surprise someone.

Comment: @jazZRo I believe it does. If I add a file to such a list I will assume I need to look for it at the end of the list, not in the middle.

Comment: What I mean is: Even when you know what is expected by most people, still someone will think that it will appear between file 1 and 3, someone will think it will appear at the bottom and another will think it will appear at the top. Whatever you choose it will always confuse someone. So it doesn't matter from UX perspective. What matters is how you show the user the (location of the) new file, so that is what you should be focussing on imo.

Comment: @jazZRo Let's put it this way - the files need to have a name. We should strive to make that name being predictable by as many people as possible. And developing supporting UX mechanisms for any solution that is not 100% foolproof is a very bad practice I think. Especially since no such mechanism is going to be 100% foolproof itself.

Comment: Well the only thing I tried to say is, don't waste too much time on this question because if predictability is key and you can't guarantee it to be predictable, just keep it to conventions like the solution in Windows if that is what people are used to and focus on other ways to improve the experience.

Comment: @jazZRo I agree completely, perspective is important :).